# vim: open 4 files split horizontally AND vertically

Tags: vim, viewport

On the command line, vim can open 4 files split horizontally,

```
vim -o file1 file2 file3 file4
```

or 4 files split vertically,

```
vim -O file1 file2 file3 file4
```

How do I open 4 files such that they are split both horizontally and vertically, like this?:

```
-----------
|    |    |
| 1  |  2 |
|    |    |
-----------
|    |    |
| 3  |  4 |
|    |    |
-----------
```

Answer (score 8):

Not that elegant with `-o` or `-O`:

```
vim file4 -c 'split file2' -c 'vsplit file1' -c 'wincmd j' -c 'vsplit file3'
```

Comment: To extend the answer further: Add a function in your `.bashrc`: 
`function vim4 {
    vim $4 -c "split $2" -c "vsplit $1" -c 'wincmd j' -c "vsplit $3"
}`
Now you can use the new `vim4` command (function): `vim4  file1 file2 file3 file4`

Comment: in @RobinHsu's .bashrc comment don't forget () after vim4 in the function def. Then it works great :)

Comment: In fact, `()` can be ignored.  The following 3 forms are all acceptable for a bash function:

`vim4() {  .... }`

`function vim4 { ... }`

`function vim4() { ... }`

Answer (score 7):

This is the shortest I can come up with:

```
vim -O 1 2 -c 'sp 3' -c 'winc l"' -c 'sp 4'
```

Or more explicitly, as noted by Marcel in the comments:

```
vim -O file1 file2 -c 'split file3' -c 'wincmd l"' -c 'split file4'
```

Comment: Note that the numbers here are file names

Comment: therefore, `vim -O file1 file2 -c 'split file3' -c 'wincmd l"' -c 'split file4'`