# Open multiple files in vim with mixed splits

Tags: vim

I need to open 3 files with vim using linux terminal, but they shoud be open with mixed splits.
`"/src/main.cpp"` being the main window `"input"` and `output` are vertically split. Please refer to the image attacheed. i tried

```
vim src/main.cpp -O result -o output
```

but it opens all windows either in all vertical or all horizontal. vim help says

```
-O[N]           Open N windows, split vertically.  Otherwise it's like -o.
                If both the -o and the -O option are given, the last one on
                the command line determines how the windows will be split.
```

[image: expected result]

Comment: What do you mean "mixed splits"? You're saying the picture is what you want? Or the picture is the incorrect behavior you're getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vim: open 4 files split horizontally AND vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823705/vim-open-4-files-split-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the splits to be of different orientations, each of a specific
size, I think the best way is to write a function that you can just call that
has the desired split arrangement. I have one for a 4-way split:

```
" make a 4-way split and resize the windows how I like
function! WorkSplit()
    let l:currentWindow=winnr()
    execute "normal! :vsplit\<cr> :buffer 2\<cr>"
    execute "normal! :split\<cr> :resize -20\<cr> :b scratch2\<cr>"
    execute l:currentWindow . "wincmd w"
    execute "normal! :split\<cr> :resize -20\<cr> :b scratch1\<cr>"
endfunction

" split vim into 4 windows, load first and second files on buffers 1 and 2.
" make the bottom windows short and load scratch*.m
nnoremap <silent><Leader>4 :call WorkSplit()<cr>
```

You'll notice that this function is not very general - it looks for two files
named scratch1 and scratch2 - which I often have in my projects - and tries to
put them in the two lower splits. So if I have open 4 files in vim called A, B,
scratch1 and scratch2, doing `Leader`+`4` will do this:

```
-----------------
|       |       |
|   A   |  B    |
|       |       |
|       |       |
-----------------
| scr1  | scr2  |
-----------------
```

If I don't have the scratch1 and scratch2 files, the function will complain,
but still create the splits (the lower splits will simply contain the 3rd and
4th files.